# Is there an efficient way in Python to subset a string between parentheses?

Tags: python, string, substring, data-cleaning

```
med2['Medication'] = ["Terazosin Hydrochloride (Terazosin) oral capsule", "simvastatin oral tablet", "zithromax z-pak (azithromycin) oral tablet", "depo-medrol (methylprednisolone) injectable suspension", "zovirax topical (acyclovir topical) topical ointment", "nystatin oral suspension"]

med3 = pd.DataFrame(med2) # Made a dataframe to try to fix some error messages

med3 = med3['Medication'].str.lower()
```

I would like to do two things:

1. select the medication name (for example above, "terazosin hydrochloride") and
2. select the generic name between the parentheses(for the example above, "terazosin").

For #1, I made a list of "stop" words/characters (my real list is longer than the above example):

```
stop = ['(', 'oral', 'nasal', 'inhalation', 'topical', 'sublingual', 'opthalmic', 'otic', 'rectal', 'injectable', 'transdermal', 'vaginal', 'intramuscular', 'dose', 'suspension', 'subcutaneous']

med3['MedShort'] = med3['Medication'][:stop]
```

For #2, I made "Index" and "End":

```
Index =  med3['Medication'].find('(')
End = med3['Medication'].find(')')

med3['MedGeneric'] = med3['Medication'][Index:End]
```

But oh boy, is it not working. Do you have any recommendations? I would appreciate it!

Edited for consistent variable naming, with apologies.

And for clarification, Medication is not consistent. Most follow the pattern of "medication (generic) administration route" but a significant number follow the pattern of medication administration route".  Thank you for your patience, apologies that I was not clear.
\

Comment: Is it 'Medication' or 'MedicationName'?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly what you expect. For example. Do you always want to stop before '(' or could it change. Have you got a more consistant dataset for being sure not missing a case?

Comment: I've edited for consistent "Medication" as the name.

Thank you, Everless Drop 41, I'll try that to extract the generic name!

Lumber Jack, it varies. Most records have the medication (generic) and then "oral tablet" or "topical cream", but some have no generic in parentheses, such as "Nystatin oral suspension".

Answer (score 0):

If all of your strings have the same structure, then

```
string = "Terazosin Hydrochloride (Terazosin) oral capsule"
drug_name, rest = string.split(" (")
generic = rest.split(")")[0]

print(drug_name.lower(), generic.lower())
```

will output `terazosin hydrochloride` and `terazosin`

Comment: Thank you! 

Most follow the pattern above, but some are like "digoxin oral tablet", which is why I had that "stop" list.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you mean. Can you give more examples in the original code that would cover all the cases you have in your data set?

Comment: I hope this helps make more sense:

simvastatin oral tablet

zithromax z-pak (azithromycin) oral tablet
atenolol oral tablet 
nexium (esomeprazole) oral delayed release capsule 
nasonex (mometasone nasal) nasal spray 
depo-medrol (methylprednisolone) injectable suspension 
flector patch (diclofenac topical) topical film, extended release
nuvaring (ethinyl estradiol-etonogestrel) vaginal ring 
metrogel-vaginal (metronidazole topical) vaginal gel with applicator   
zovirax topical (acyclovir topical) topical ointment